# How to use custom authentication in my view

Tags: python, django-2.0

I have  a custom authentication backend that logs in user with using either username or email. But it keeps throwing several errors:

**`auth_backend.py:`**

```
class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    This is a ModelBacked that allows authentication with either a username or an email address.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = Farmer.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Farmer.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return Farmer.objects.get(pk=username)
        except Farmer.DoesNotExist:
            return None


authenticate = EmailOrUsernameModelBackend.authenticate
```

**`views.py:`**

```
from .auth_backend import authenticate

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('stories')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")
    else:
        return render(request, 'stories/login.html', {})
```

I keep getting either `self is missing` or `Invalid login details given` even when using correct credentials.

Comment: In `authenticate` you pass _email_ `return Farmer.objects.get(email=email, password=password)`, however in `user_login` you pass _username_ `user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Thanks. That's a typo. I've made changes to the file.

Comment: It looks like your authentication is probably working fine, but the user is inactive (`is_active = False`). If authentication fails, then it returns `None` in which case you'd get an exception for `if user.is_active`.

Comment: Thanks, but from my end, the user is active...

Comment: Oh, I removed `user.check_password(user.password)` from auth_backend and it works. Thanks everyone.